# Simple question regarding closure and subsets

Tags: general-topology

This is probably a dumb question but I have overthought the result so thought it would be best to ask it on here. Suppose I have two compact sets $A$ and $B$ and denote their interiors as int$(A)$ and int$(B)$. Are the two below statements equivalent?

Statement $1$: $\text{int}(A) \subseteq \text{int}(B)$

Statement $2$: $A \subseteq B$

Comment: $B = [0,1]$ and $A=B\cup\{2\}$

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: I have uploaded an updated version of this question, with an additional assumption, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216728/simple-question-regarding-closure-and-subsets-with-condition-on-interior