# Simple question regarding closure and subsets, with condition on interior

Tags: general-topology

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216697/simple-question-regarding-closure-and-subsets) and got a very quick answer. I realize now that I should have included an extra condition. I have included the new condition in the modified version of the question below.

---

Suppose I have two compact sets $A$ and $B$ and denote their interiors as int$(A)$ and int$(B)$. Suppose, additionally, that I know that $A=\overline{\text{int}(A)}$ and $B=\overline{\text{int}(B)}$ where $\overline{C}$ represents the closure of $C$.

Are the two below statements equivalent?

Statement $1$: $\text{int}(A) \subseteq \text{int}(B)$

Statement $2$: $A \subseteq B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two facts here are needed. The first is that $int$ preserves the subset relation - that is, $X \subseteq Y$ implies $int(X) \subseteq int(Y)$. This follows from the relation $U \subseteq int(X)$ iff $U \subseteq X$ for all open $U$, since we have $U \subseteq int(X)$ implies $U \subseteq X$ implies $U \subseteq Y$ implies $U \subseteq int(Y)$, hence $int(X) \subseteq int(Y)$ (taking $U = int(X)$).

From the above fact, (2) clearly implies (1).

Similarly, closure preserves the subset relation. This follows from the relation $\overline{X} \subseteq C$ iff $X \subseteq C$ for all closed $C$. From this, if $X \subseteq Y$ then for all closed $C$, then for all closed $C$, $\overline{Y} \subseteq C$ implies $Y \subseteq C$ implies $X \subseteq C$ implies $\overline{X} \subseteq C$; hence, $\overline{X} \subseteq \overline{Y}$ since $\overline{Y}$ is closed.

From the above fact, (1) implies (2). For if $int(A) \subseteq int(B)$, then $A = \overline{int(A)} \subseteq \overline{int(B)} = B$.

Comment: Why do you you think $A = \overline{int(A)}$?

Comment: @fleablood "Suppose, additionally, that I know that $A = \overline{int(A)}$". It was explicitly stated in the problem.

Comment: Oh.... Dang my blind middle-aged eyes!  That changes *everything*!

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you!

Comment: @JDoe2 I didn't mention this in the answer, but note that compactness is totally irrelevant here. And you're welcome.

Comment: Hmm yes thank you for point that out to me - I thought maybe there could be some strange examples if you had a half plane or something along those lines!

Answer (score 1):

If $\overline{(int A)} = A$ then for any $x \in A$ so that $x \not \in int A$ then $x$ is a limit point of $int A$. (and thus also a limit point of $A$).

In order for $int(A)\subset int (B)$ but $A \not \subset B$

there must be a point $x\in A$ where $x \not \in B$.  For that to be true we can't have $x \in int A$ (or else $x \in int (B)\subset B$) so we must have $x$ is a limit point of $int A$ (but is not an interior point of $A$) but is not a point of $B$ (thus not a limit point of $B$ [as $B$ is closed], nor a limit point of $int B$, nor an interior point of $B$).

So $x$ is a limit point of $int A$ so for any $r>0$ then $N_r(x)$ will contain an interior point point of $a'\in int A$.  And thus there is $d$ so that $N_d(a')\subset int A\subset int B$. But that means $a'\in int B$ so $x$ *is* a limit point of $\int B$  and therefore $x$ *IS* a point of $\overline{int B}=B$ after all!.

So...  $int(A) \subset int B \implies A \subset B$.

In order for $A \subset B$ but $int A \not \subset B$

there must be a point $x \in int A$ but $x \not \in int B$.

But that's easily shown to be impossible.  If $x\in int A$ then there exists a $d > 0$ so that $N_r(x)\subset A \subset B$ so $x$ is an interior point of $B$.

......

So yes, the statements are equivalent...

!!!***IF***!!! $A=\overline{int A}$ and $B=\overline{int B}$.

Note if $A = [0,2]\cup \{3,4,5\}$ then ${int A} = (0,2)$ and $\overline{int A} = [0,2] \ne A$ and if we have $B = [0,2]$ then......

......

However $A\subset B \implies int(A) \subset int (B)$ regardless of anything else (not the argument is just if $x\in int(A)$ then there is a neigborhood of $x$ entirely withing $A$ and thus entirely within $B$-- nothing other than $A \subset B$ was used)

And if $C \subset D$  then $\overline C \subset \overline D$ is always true (because if $x$ is a limit point of $C$ then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $C$ with must also be a point of $D$ so $x$ is also a limit point of $D$).

Those are very handy and important results.  But if a set has weird pesky points that are neither interior nor limit points then the throw this off.  (But those points can usually be brushed off like coffee grounds as unimportant.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will take note of the coffee grounds! :)